# How to reformat a conditional density plot in R?

Tags: r, graphics, plot

The following reproducible example creates a [conditional density plot](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/cdplot.html) depicting change by aspect.  I've included NoData in the example because my original dataset also has NoData.

```
aspect = c("N", "N", "E", "S", "SW", "SW", "E", "W", "N", "N")
change = c(-1, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, NA)
mydata = data.frame(aspect,change)

x = factor(mydata$change)

cdplot(x~mydata$aspect)
```

[image]

Related Questions:

- How do I replace the numerical values on the X-axis with the
  associated text values (e.g. N, SW, etc)?
- Is it possible to have control over the order of text values on the
  X-axis?  I believe, by default, the values on the X-axis correspond
  to the alphabetically ordered text values in "aspect".
- How do I replace "NA" on the X-axis with "No Change"?

Comment: I know nothing about this type of plots, but judging from the help page, you are doing it wrong. Quote: "Computes and plots conditional densities describing how the conditional distribution of a **categorical variable y** changes over a **numerical variable x**."

Comment: @Roland In this case, the y variable is categorical (i.e. positive or negative change) and the x variable translates to frequency of aspect, which is a numerical variable.

Comment: `mydata$aspect`is not `numeric`, but a `factor`, which gets created, when you put the `character` `vector` into the `data.frame`. The function then coerces the `factor` to a `numeric`. In the examples on the help page x is a `numeric` (temperature). If `aspect` can be expressed as a `numeric`you should do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to show what @Roland said in the comments, you use the function in a wrong manner.

```
aspect = c("N", "N", "E", "S", "SW", "SW", "E", "W", "N", "N")
change = sample(rep(c(-1,1,NA), each = 100),100,replace=T)
mydata = data.frame(aspect,change,stringsAsFactors=T)
str(mydata)
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  2 variables:
 $aspect: Factor
$change: num 
h <- cdplot(aspect~change, data = mydata)
```

[image]

and now h contains the conditional density functions over the levels of aspect.

```
str(h)
List of 4
 $ E :function (v)  
 $ N :function (v)  
 $ S :function (v)  
 $ SW:function (v)
```

e.g

```
h$E(-Inf)
[1] 0.21875
h$E(Inf)
[1] 0.25
```